# Using GSON to deserialize nested array

Tags: android, json, gson

Giving

**JSON**

```
// imagine this is JSON of a city
{
    "title" : "Troy"
    "people" : [
        {
            {
                "title" : "Hector",
                "status" : "Dead"
            },
            {
                "title" : "Paris",
                "status" : "Run Away"
            }
        },
        ...
    ],
    "location" : "Mediteranian",
    "era" : "Ancient",
    ...
}
```

**City**

```
public class City {
    @SerializeName("title")
    String title;
    @SerializeName("people")
    List<Person> people;
    @SerializeName("location")
    String location;
    @SerializeName("era")
    String era;
    ...
}
```

**Person**

```
public class Person {
    @SerializeName("title")
    private String title;
    @SerializeName("status")
    private String status;
}
```

If having string of JSON above, it is possible to create list of person

A. without having to deserialize City first like following

```
City city = new Gson().fromJson(json, City.class)
ArrayList<Person> people = city.people;
```

And

B. without having to convert string to JSONObject, get JSONArray and then convert back to string like following

```
String peopleJsonString = json.optJSONArray("people").toString
ArrayList<Person> people = new Gson().fromJSON(peopleJsonString, Person.class);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom JsonDeserializer, which is part of Gson (`com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer`).

Simple example:

```
public class WhateverDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Whatever> {
  @Override
  public Whatever deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    Whatever whatever = new Whatever();
    // Fetch the needed object here
    // whatever.setNeededObject(neededObject);
    return whatever;
  }
}
```

You can then apply this deserializer like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Whatever.class, new WhateverDeserializer())
            .create();
```

There is a full example of how to use a custom deserializer, including a super detailed explanation, on this page: http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the list directly without parsing the json array. You need to parse the array. And it would be faster via Gson;

If you strictly need (only array) and you won't be using any other json object . Simply delete them, so that gson won't parse them.

Comment: Take a closer look to the question and the limitations that @Tar_Tw45 set.